# iso_fortran_env kind values not compile-time constant

Tags: fortran

I ran into an issue with abstract interfaces.

I'm trying to declare an abstract interface with specific kinds of the arguments, and I want to use the `iso_fortran_env` kind descriptors rather than hard-coded numbers to keep it compiler-independent. Here's an example:

```
module ExampleFunc
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: real64
    implicit none
contains
    real(kind=real64) function f(x)
        real(kind=real64), intent(in) :: x
        f = x**2
    end function f
end module ExampleFunc

program ExampleProc
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: real64
    use ExampleFunc, only: f
    implicit none
    abstract interface
        real(kind=real64) function func(x)
            real(kind=real64), intent(in) :: x
        end function func
    end interface
    procedure (func), pointer :: f_ptr => NULL()

    f_ptr => f

    print *, f_ptr(2.0_real64)
end program ExampleProc
```

But when I try to compile it, I get an error message:

```
         real(kind=real64) function func(x)
                  1
Error: Parameter ‘real64’ at (1) has not been declared or is a 
variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
```

(This is with `gfortran` v5.4.0, but I get a similar error message with `ifort` as well.)

I get the same error if instead of using `iso_fortran_env` I set the parameter manually, like this: `integer, parameter :: real64 = 8`, so evading to `selected_real_kind` won't work either.

Only if I literally replace the `real64` with `8` in the abstract interface block will it compile.

Any idea how to keep this code compiler-independent? Thanks

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857867/how-to-use-a-user-defined-type-in-a-fortran-interface/13858145#13858145

Comment: Of course it's a dupe !

Comment: I'm not surprised that it's a duplicate, but without understanding the reason behind the error it's often hard to find the duplicate in the vast database of stackoverflow. For example, I was searching for 'compile-time constant' -- but that term doesn't appear in the original at all.

Comment: Anyway, thank you.