# Two constructors "pattern" and operator overloading with type "inhomogeneity"

Tags: fortran

I wanted to create a date type with day, month and year as data components and with a second constructor allowing for a date construction not from day, month and year but from a serial number (1 for january the 1st, 1900, 2 for january the 2nd, 1900 and so on).

```
module Date
implicit none

    type :: t_Date
        integer :: Day
        integer :: Month
        integer :: Year
    end type
    
    interface t_Date
        procedure :: new_t_Date
    end interface t_Date
    
    
    
    contains

    
    type(t_Date) function new_t_Date(serial)
    
        integer, intent(in) :: serial
        integer :: l, n, i, j
        l = serial + 68569 + 2415019
        n = int(( 4 * l ) / 146097)
        l = l - int(( 146097 * n + 3 ) / 4)
        i = int(( 4000 * ( l + 1 ) ) / 1461001)
        l = l - int(( 1461 * i ) / 4) + 31
        j = int(( 80 * l ) / 2447)
        new_t_Date%Day = l - int(( 2447 * j ) / 80)
        l = int(j / 11)
        new_t_Date%Month = j + 2 - ( 12 * l )
        new_t_Date%Year = 100 * ( n - 49 ) + i + l
    
    end function new_t_Date
    
    function get_serial(date) result(serial)
    
        type(t_Date), intent(in) :: date
        integer :: serial
        serial = int(( 1461 * ( date%Year + 4800 + int(( date%Month - 14 ) / 12) ) ) / 4) + int(( 367 * ( date%Month - 2 - 12 * ( ( date%Month - 14 ) / 12 ) ) ) / 12) - int(( 3 * ( int(( date%Year + 4900 + int(( date%Month - 14 ) / 12) ) / 100) ) ) / 4) + date%Day - 2415019 - 32075;
    
    end function get_serial
    
    function date_substract(d1,d2) result (n)
        type(t_Date), intent(in) :: d1,d2
        integer :: n
        n = get_serial(d1) - get_serial(d2)
    end function date_substract
    
    !interface operator (-)
    !    function date_substract(d1,d2) result (n)
    !        type(t_Date), intent(in) :: d1,d2
    !        integer :: n
    !    end function date_substract
    !end interface
    
end module Date
```

To get the second constructor pattern, I used the interface bit :

```
    interface t_Date
        procedure :: new_t_Date
    end interface t_Date
```

(The code inside `type(t_Date) function new_t_Date(serial)` and `function get_serial(date) result(serial)` does not really matter as my issue is formal.)

Now, I want to implement the difference between two dates, giving the number of calendar days between them.

This is the function :

```
    function date_substract(d1,d2) result (n)
        type(t_Date), intent(in) :: d1,d2
        integer :: n
        n = get_serial(d1) - get_serial(d2)
    end function date_substract
```

Now, instead of calling `date_substract` for the difference of two dates, I would rather call the difference operator `-` by overloading it.

The over loading code (commented above) is :

```
    interface operator (-)
        function date_substract(d1,d2) result (n)
            type(t_Date), intent(in) :: d1,d2
            integer :: n
        end function date_substract
    end interface
```

Wherever I place it in my code, I have errors.

I don't know where to place it, nor if (as in `c++`) it is possible in Fortran to overload an operator by changing its signature, introducing type inhomogeneity : the `-` takes two elements of the same type to return an element of the same type while in my case it should take two date and return an `integer`

Comment: "Wherever I place it in my code, I have errors." What are the errors?

Comment: The interface needs to go before the line `contains` in your module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fortran function to overload multiplication between derived types with allocatable components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230199/fortran-function-to-overload-multiplication-between-derived-types-with-allocatab)

Comment: If I uncomment it I have (intel compiler) a `error #7111: An interface-body is incorrectly positioned within a program unit`. This I understand. If I put it just between the end of the `interface t_Date` and the `contains` I have a `An explicit INTENT(IN) declaration is expected for this dummy argument of the defined operation` for the `intent(in)` inside the interface, a `This derived type name has not been declared` for the `t_date` in it and a `The name of the module procedure conflicts with a name in the encompassing scoping unit` for the use of `date_substract` at the end of the code.

Comment: @veryreverie Yes, but when I put it before the `contains`, I also have the errors mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @veryreverie The answer you pointed to indeed solved my question (namely the `INTERFACE OPERATOR(*)
    MODULE PROCEDURE CDS_mat_x_CDS_mat
  END INTERFACE OPERATOR(*)` bit), thank you very much. But I don't understand why my synthax (found on https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys466/sp2013/comp_info/overload.html and adapted) is wrong. Would you consider make an answer developing on that ?

Comment: Is his relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857867/how-to-use-a-user-defined-type-in-a-fortran-interface/13858145#13858145

Comment: Oh ok, so would I have `Import :: t_Date` (a foward declaration) it would have made type available in the interface and my initial code (modified with the import) would have worked ... Great